# change default close button in jquery mobile dialog header?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a regular jquery mobile dialog with a default close button to the left in the header. I'm trying to change the close button to a back button, and at the same time give it a back icon (data-icon="arrow-l"? I've tried to make some changes in the first a tag below, but the result is an empty button in front of the old close button, and the OK button (second a tag) moves to the left instead of staying to the right. The image within the h1 tags is pushed below the buttons but stays centered.

```
 <div data-role="header" class="header">
    <a class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="arrow-l" href="#" title="back" data-theme="a">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-rel="check" title="Ok"></a>
            <h1><img src="<?= base_url(); ?>/branding/img/logo.png" height="20" /></h1>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data-close-btn="none" and use the data-rel="back" like this:

```
<div data-role="header" class="header" data-close-btn="none"> 
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="check" title="Ok"></a>

  <h1><img src="<?= base_url(); ?>/branding/img/logo.png" height="20" /></h1>
</div>
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BAVg/1/).
Is this what you meant?